# Group the result from DATEDIFF function in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this query :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,wj_date,wj_donedate) AS tmpDay
FROM wssjobm , sysbrxces  WHERE wj_br = zu_br AND zu_user = 'mbs' 
AND wj_date >= '2013/04/01' AND wj_date <= '2013/04/30' 
AND wj_status = 'D' AND wj_donedate <= '2013/04/30'
```

The eg. result :

```
tmpDay
1
11
5
1
7
2
12
10
2
2
```

How can i group by the result and count it using query to be like this :

```
tmpDay count
  1     2
  2     3
  5     1
  7     1
  10    1
  11    1
  12    1
```

thanks!

Extra Question :

May i get the result like this :

```
tmpDayGroup Count
   1- 4       5
   5- 8       2
   11 -12     3
```

Comment: If am not wrong this is related `MsSql server` ,  which have added while editing ur post ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  tmpDay, 
  COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM 
  YourTable 
Group By tmpDay
```

For the given example, query should be like:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(DAY,wj_date,wj_donedate) AS tmpDay,
    COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM 
    wssjobm , sysbrxces  
WHERE 
    wj_br = zu_br AND 
    zu_user = 'mbs' AND 
    wj_date >= '2013/04/01' AND 
    wj_date <= '2013/04/30' AND 
    wj_status = 'D' AND 
    wj_donedate <= '2013/04/30'
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(DAY,wj_date,wj_donedate)
```

For grouping the result, try:

```
;with T as(
    select '1' FrmD, '4' ToD union all
    select '5' FrmD, '8' ToD union all
    select '9' FrmD, '12' ToD 
)
select 
    T.FrmD +'-'+ T.ToD tmpDayGroup, 
    COUNT(*) [Count] 
from T Left Join (
    SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(DAY,wj_date,wj_donedate) AS tmpDay
    FROM 
        wssjobm , sysbrxces  
    WHERE 
        wj_br = zu_br AND 
        zu_user = 'mbs' AND 
        wj_date >= '2013/04/01' AND 
        wj_date <= '2013/04/30' AND 
        wj_status = 'D' AND 
        wj_donedate <= '2013/04/30'
) T2 on T2.tmpDay between T.FrmD and T.ToD
group by T.FrmD, T.ToD
```

Comment: i've extra question. may u help me? please refer above. i already edit.

Comment: the result from DATEDIFF. 
Which mean,i want to group the tmpDay
and count how many data got tmpDay between 1 - 4 days, 5- 7, etc

Comment: Thansk for your help.. really appreciate it. :)